# Funcion SQL, como hacer que tome como referencia el UTC y no la hora de mi sistema

Tags: sql, funciones

Como puedo hacer que tome de referencia Coordinated Universal Time (UTC), lo que hace mi codigo es tomar la hora de mi sistema.

```
create function dbo.zonahr(  @TimeZoneName sysname)
RETURNS datetime2
AS
BEGIN
 
  RETURN DATEADD(hour, 
                 TRY_CAST((SELECT REPLACE(current_utc_offset, N':', N'.')
                           FROM sys.time_zone_info 
                           WHERE [name] = @TimeZoneName) AS decimal(18,2)), 
                 SYSDATETIME());
END;
GO


SELECT dbo.zonahr ('Hawaiian Standard Time'); --Zona horaria de hawaii como ejemplo

select * from sys.time_zone_info -- lista de zonas horarias
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solo necesitas usar la función `SYSUTCDATETIME()`, pero asegurate de tener configurado correctamente tu servidor.

También puedes leer acerca del uso del tipo de dato [datetimeoffset](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/datetimeoffset-transact-sql).